# If $X_n$ sequence of random variables , equally distributed $EX_n=a, n=1,2,3...$ then $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k\to^{P}a$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence, characteristic-functions

If $X_n$ sequence of random variables , equally distributed $EX_n=a, n=1,2,3...$ then $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k\to^{P}a$ (convergence in probability)

Proof: (using the fact that convergence in distribution to a constant $a$ implies convergence in probability to that constant)

$$f-\text{ characteristic function }\\ f_{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k}(t)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}f_{X_k}(\frac{t}{n})\text{ this is clear why but the next two equalities are not}\\ = \prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+\frac{ait}{n}+ \sigma(\frac{t}{n}))\text{ I'm told this is Maclaurin series, I dont see how...  }\\ =(1+\frac{ait}{n}+ \sigma(\frac{t}{n}))^n\to_{n\to \infty}**e^{ait}**=f_a(t)$$

I put in stars what I would like to know most..

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the $\sigma$ is meant to be "little o" notation.

Comment: You're missing any assumption of independence. Without something of the kind, the result is not true.

Comment: Correct i forgot to add this.

Comment: So your Maclaurin series is actually the Taylor expansion of the characteristic function - just try to check this out and you'll understand how the $o$ notation (yes, Shalop is right) comes into play and describes the progression of the residium. Please add the independence assumption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first equality that you don't understand is indeed a MacLaurin series expansion of the characteristic function, using the link between the moments of a random variable and the derivatives of the characteristic function. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Moments .

So Shalop is right, the $\sigma$ is a little o.

Then you use the fact that $\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\rightarrow e^x$. You can take the $\ln$ if it's not clear. Finally, we see $e^{ait}$ as the characteristic function of the distribution $\delta_a$, which is the distribution of a random variable constantly equal to $a$.